# Searching in a Relational table and getting the correct count

Tags: mysql, sql

In this Query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fee4c6/3/0

```
SELECT d.`id`, COUNT(da.`doc_id`), COUNT(db.`doc_id`)
FROM `docs` d

LEFT JOIN `docs_scod_a` da ON da.`doc_id` = d.`id`
LEFT JOIN `scod_a` a ON a.id = da.`doc_id`

LEFT JOIN `docs_scod_b` db ON db.`doc_id` = d.`id`
LEFT JOIN `scod_a` b ON b.`id` = db.`doc_id`

GROUP BY d.`id`
```

I'm supposed to each `doc_id` and its `scod_x` count of records having the same `d.id = x.doc_id`

So, The expected result is:

```
| id | COUNT(da.`doc_id`) | COUNT(db.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |                  3 |                  3 |
|  2 |                  3 |                  1 |
|  3 |                  2 |                  3 |
|  4 |                  0 |                  1 |
```

But what I get instead is:

```
| id | COUNT(da.`doc_id`) | COUNT(db.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |                  9 |                  9 |
|  2 |                  3 |                  3 |
|  3 |                  6 |                  6 |
|  4 |                  0 |                  1 |
```

At the same time I want to exclude records by `IN() clause`, so for `WHERE a.ver_a IN ('AA') AND b.ver_b IN ('BA')` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fee4c6/2/0

I'm supposed to get:

```
| id | COUNT(da.`doc_id`) | COUNT(db.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |                  3 |                  3 |
```

But I get

```
| id | COUNT(da.`doc_id`) | COUNT(db.`doc_id`) |
|----|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |                  9 |                  9 |
```

What is the problem exactly and How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT d.`id`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `docs_scod_a` da WHERE da.`doc_id` = d.`id`) as cda,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `docs_scod_b` db WHERE db.`doc_id` = d.`id`) as cdb
FROM `docs` d;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db8589/54

Note that you don't need to touch the tables `scod_a` and `scod_b`.

**Update**

To use a condition on the `scod_a` and `scod_d` tables you would need a JOIN in the subqueries:

```
SELECT d.`id`,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `docs_scod_a` da
    JOIN `scod_a` a ON a.id = da.`doc_id`
    WHERE da.`doc_id` = d.`id`
      AND a.ver_a IN ('A')
  ) as cda,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `docs_scod_b` db
    JOIN `scod_b` b ON b.`id` = db.`doc_id`
    WHERE db.`doc_id` = d.`id`
      AND b.ver_b IN ('A')
  ) as cdb
FROM `docs` d;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db8589/68

Comment: That would work perfectly, But how can I search using `IN() clause` by names coming from `scod_x`, each `A, B, C, D` in each table is a name different from each other.

Comment: Is it not possible to make it filter the values to exclude the `0` values? since  I expect one row, getting all the not related to the `IN()` would be a lot, Would a DERIVED join work better than Subquery?

Comment: @Toleo `HAVING cda + cdb > 0` maybe? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db8589/70